# How to create VSPackage project from VisualStudio2015?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, vs-extensibility

I have installed Visual studio 2015 SDk from the below mentioned site.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx 
Then tried to create VS extension project, but VSshellisolated project only available under OtherProjects->Extensibility . what can i do to create project on VSPackage project type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got solution to my problem from the below link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1dcc380-d87d-4f76-89ff-07a65b917640/vs-extension-from-vs2015?forum=vsx#ec3165d6-7230-4afb-8254-7959547c2c5d